# Test Angular resolve method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have Angular with ui-router, so `toResolve` variable will be resolved in my `SomeController`

```
.state('some.state', {
      url: '/some',
      controller: 'SomeController',
      templateUrl: '/static/views/some-state.html',
      resolve: {
        toResolve: function(Resource) {
          return Resource.get(function(response) {
            return response;
          });
        },
```

But how to test this functionality with Jasmine? Let's suppose that I forget `return` statement, therefore the `toResolve` in my scope will be *undefined*.

Comment: Why you want to test internal AngularJS functionality, probably it works in the perfect way

Comment: It's not the internals, it's a simple test case like `expect($scope.toResolve).not.toBeUndefined();` when I might miss return for example

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski: anyway, everything have to be testable and if I want to I should be able to mock any component and test any combination of those regardless of is it internal or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use services to make resolvers efficiently testable (and also mockable in integration/e2e tests).

*Note: Angular services are singletons, state/route resolvers are not.*

If caching a resolution is expected, a resolver may be moved to `factory` service.

```
app.factory('someResolver', function(Resource) {
  return Resource.get(function(response) {
    return response;
  })
});
...

resolve: { toResolve: 'someResolver' },
```

On the other hand, if the resolver is expected to be evaluated on each route change, this may lead to undesirable app behaviour. In this case the appropriate recipe may be `constant` annotated function:

```
app.constant('someResolver', ['Resource', function(Resource) {
  return Resource.get(function(response) {
    return response;
  })
}]);

app.config(function (someResolver, ...) {
  ...
  resolve: { toResolve: someResolver },
  ...
```

Otherwise the specs may end encumbered with a pile of boilerplate code:

```
var toResolveFactory = $state.get('some.state').resolve.toResolve;
var toResolve = $injector.invoke(toResolveFactory);
```

Comment: Great, that was exactly what I was looking for. Another small question for you: where `$injector` in my spec came from?

Comment: @MostWanted You will need to inject `$injector` service into spec to test both `constant` and `$state.get...` flavours of resolvers (not necessary for `factory`).

Answer (score 0):

One good article on related topic is http://nikas.praninskas.com/angular/2014/09/27/unit-testing-ui-router-configuration/, but it's not the solution. One idea is to pass another object to `resolve` and then test that unit of code separately which is good when you're resolving a bunch of items.